# Some confusions about source code of Json11

Tags: c++, json, c++11

When I read the source code of `Json11`, I found something that puzzled me.

```
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Static globals - static-init-safe
     */
    struct Statics {
        const std::shared_ptr<JsonValue> null = make_shared<JsonNull>();
        const std::shared_ptr<JsonValue> t = make_shared<JsonBoolean>(true);
        const std::shared_ptr<JsonValue> f = make_shared<JsonBoolean>(false);
        const string empty_string;
        const vector<Json> empty_vector;
        const map<string, Json> empty_map;
        Statics() {}
    };

    static const Statics & statics() {
        static const Statics s {};
        return s;
    }

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Constructors
 */

Json::Json() noexcept                  : m_ptr(statics().null) {}
Json::Json(std::nullptr_t) noexcept    : m_ptr(statics().null) {}
```

Why does the function `statics` return a reference value `s` that declared as static const?

Why use the function `statics` to get the member null?

Comment: "_Why the function statics return a reference value s_" So that one wouldn't return a copy of the object?

Comment: It's the thread safe (C++11) singleton pattern.

Comment: It looks like it is a singleton but with a public default constructor it is not so IDK.

Comment: You should explain why you think _not_! Can't correct a misunderstanding we haven't been told about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Statics` struct, as the comment states, is meant to hold constant values that are used repeatedly across the code. Instead of creating multiple instances of these frequently-used objects, only one is necessary, reducing the memory usage (and maybe making comparison easier). The function `statics()` returns a reference to a unique, global instance of the `Statics` struct. This is somewhat like a [singleton pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern), although, as [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) pointed out, `Statics` still has a public constructor, so there is nothing stopping you from creating new instances of the struct.

The constructor of `Json` uses the kind-of-singleton `Statics` instance to get it's `null` member, which is a pointer to a `JsonNull` object. This means that every new `Json` object is created with null value, but the same instance of `JsonNull` is used to initialize all of them. Since both the `Statics` object and its members are `const`, there is (in principle) no possibility of modifying the static data by accident.